# Smooth curve with 1 or more control points? (Monotone interpolation)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

*First of, i am really sorry if i poorly described my question, i am no mathematician but i need to figure this out for my project, and i am having hard time finding the formula.*

I work with numbers from 1-10
Where 1 is 1, 5 is 5 and 10 is 10 - Linear (as expected)

But i need to make my set of numbers like this
1 is 1, 5 is 2.5 and 10 is 10 - This would be a smooth curve like in my image bellow:

[My Image - Smooth curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6BDp.png)

The red line represents thew result where the black dotted line is the linear 1-10. B is the point that i want to be able to control

Alternatively, i might also need to be able more control points later on in addition to "B".

(I need to be able to write this in a function where it would calculate the new value for any given number based on the control point B, e.g. i plug 5 i get 2.5)

Thank you so much

edit: The curve between 1 - 10 must stay positive and be smooth (without bumps)

edit2: @Rahul [suggested Monotone cubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation#Monotone_cubic_Hermite_interpolation), i think that's what i am after

The thing is i need to use this in my program i am writing, and i have no clue how.

I've found [a video where it's used in excel](https://youtu.be/Q_xJnzO8bG8?t=4m33s) (but the algorithm isn't provided). How could i use that as the guy inputs numbers and gets interpolation? (algorithm /formula)?

Comment: There could be infinitely many functions like this. I can find an answer to your question if you specify the function must be a polynomial of a given degree (for example, it must be quadratic or it must be cubic).

Comment: @UmerAmjad i am not really sure Umer, did you see the image in the link? How can i know if i need quadratic or cubic (https://i.stack.imgur.com/A6BDp.png - the curve i draw will help?)

Comment: It depends on how many "control points" you want to add later. Here's an example of creating a quadratic between points (0, 0) and (10,10) and (5, B):
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/7ozmrygknd
If you slide B, you'll see that the function $f$ will change so that the value at 5 becomes B. Is this something like what you're looking for, but you want a more general solution?

Comment: What about $f(x)=10\times(x/10)^{\alpha}$? (For example, let $\alpha=2$ for $f(5)=2.5$)

Comment: Here's an example of a more general approach to finding polynomials between n points:
http://2000clicks.com/mathhelp/geometrypointsdeterminepolynomial.aspx

Comment: @UmerAmjad that demo site you linked is very illustrative.     
edit1: the problem with that example is that when i slide B to value of 1.2 in there i get negative values - i need to stay positive all the time from 1- 10
     
edit2: i might need to ad maybe 2-3 points more at max later on (but maybe not - this might do the job )

Comment: I see, it's harder to guarantee something like the function must remain positive, as even if you added more points for positivity, it could still be negative _between_ the points one specifies. I've updated my example to enforce f(1) = 1, and that allows it to remain positive for _most_ positive values for B: close to 0, it still becomes negative, and the function now has more "bumps": https://www.desmos.com/calculator/3f6t3metss

Comment: @UmerAmjad Thank you for helping me out Umer, i highly appreciate it, though i can't use that function, i must get a smooth curve  :( - suggestions?; edit: i mean without bumps

Comment: [Monotone cubic interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation) may be what you need.

Comment: @UmerAmjad i think i have to use Monotonic cubic interpolation as suggested, since my values are only increasing from 1 to 10.

Now i just need to figure out how to use the formula (yeah i am that bad :S )

Comment: @Rahul i think that will serve me (just i need to figure out how to use the correct formula now, so when i plug in one number i get the interpolated)

thanks

Comment: @Rahul i'v read the wiki article you linked, with no success, can you help me understand how i can use the monotonic interpolation in an algorithm?

As i said, my values will be from 1-10; Now in example, i  set point 5 to be 2.5, and 1 and 10 are fixed, everything in between gets interpolated. 

How can i write an algorithm (formula) so i can use this in my program?
Thanks allot

Comment: First, you compute a tangent at each known point, as described in the Wikipedia article. Now you have points with attached tangents, i.e. for every known input $x$, you have both an output $y$ and a tangent $y'=dy/dx$. To interpolate at any input value in between, find the two points on either side, and do [cubic Hermite interpolation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_Hermite_spline).

Comment: @Rahul Thanks for the explanation, later today i will try it out, in the meanwhile i suggest you write an answer with 1 or 2 examples how you interpolate (so i can choose your answer as the final solution to my question), i really appreciate your help. Cheers